# Runtime want to get dynamic list from string

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, dynamic-list

I have one `List<string>` containing column names and corresponding datatype

Suppose my list is:

```
List<string> oList = { 
             "Name-Varchar", 
             "UserID-int", 
             "Address-Varchar", 
             "DBO-Date", 
             "Salary-Money" };
```

Using the above `List` want to create a dynamic list having properties **Name,UserID,Address,DBO,Salary**
Then want to fill this list by DB table information .To use this list may need to create instance.

1. On run time want to create dynamic list.
2. Fill list by DB values.
3. Declare this list globally so need to create instance of the list.

Is this possible ?

If it is possible then how should I go about it?

Please provide me some workable syntax .If you have any query please ask.

Answer (score 1):

How about a custom class for the list items, and then just add one for each row retrieved from the database?

```
public class Employee
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string UserID { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
    string DBO { get; set; }
    string Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Create your list

```
List<Employee> lstEmployees = new List<Employee>;
```

And then to add each item pop it in a loop (let's say it's in a `DataTable`):

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt)
{
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.Name = row["name"];
    e.UserID = row["userid"];
    e.Address = row["address"];
    e.DBO = row["dbo"];
    e.Salary = row["salary"];
    lstEmployees.Add(e);
}
```

Comment: Sid Holland thanks for reply,i am familiar with your above syntax ,but i want different thing ,I dont want to create any physical file names"Employee" want to create this class on run time then do the rest thing you describe in your syntax.Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This _will_ create the objects in runtime when you read the values from your database and set them up according to what's retrieved.

Comment: thanks Sid Holland for your valuable information,If you get any idea or any clue please share with us.Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want... but try this

```
List<Dictionary<string,object>> YourList = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt)
{
    Dictionary<string,object> e = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    e["name"] = row["name"];
    e["userid"] = row["userid"];
    e["address"] = row["address"];
    e["dbo"] = row["dbo"];
    e["salary"] = row["salary"];
    YourList.Add(e);
}
```

Although I don't think that this i a good idea!

Please describe your goal more clearly so a better answer can be given...

Comment: Yahia thanks for reply,I have one application where need to execute dynamic query .I know how to execute this dynamic query but after execute need to store this result in a list .I don’t  know how to create this dynamic list contain the property as defined or specified in query as a column.Need help to write a dynamic list,which create on run time .Thanks you.

Comment: @shamim your description is still unclear... how will that list be used exactly ?

Comment: To use this list need to create instance on runtime.Suppose In my project have a class contain several properties ,to access this class as a list need to declare generic list ,then we create an instance then access the list.Now I don’t want this static class ,want to create this  class on runtime after create this class want to create instance to access this list .Now if you have any obscure about my need , Please point out which information help you to understand my need.Thank you

Comment: @shamim sorry, but you are only descibing "how" not "what your goal is"... this way I can't help :-(

Comment: Yahia,hoep this description help you to understand ,why i need your help .My application has one searching page ,there user can search project related any thing ,When I use Ado.net framework  then I create one sp which capable to run dynamic query  then just catch the output and build a data-table and solve the issue,But currently  I use EF(Entity Frame work) ,here  I execute the dynamic query ,it’s not a problem but problem is after execute the query where to put the output

Comment: I want to put dynamic query output in a list ,problem is need to create this list with properties (which contain each row column value) on run time,from dynamic query I know the property name and type ,I just need to create this list on run time then bind